# He shot an arrow at/to/toward(s) the target

Tags: prepositions

> a. He shot an arrow **at** the target. 
> b. He shot an arrow **to** the target. 
> c. He shot an arrow **toward(s)** the target.

I think (a) is the correct choice in most contexts, but can (b) or (c) also be used? If so, in what context?

Comment: (c) might be used to indicate a direction when the person (the archer) knows that the target is too far away. Cannot think of a use for (b).

Comment: "To" suggests reaching a destination. ("I went to the hair dresser" has the sense of "I went as far as the hairdresser".) So in theory (b) could mean, "I shot an arrow and it travelled the full distance to the target" (which it may or may not have hit.)